# What space best describes the colour space (RGB)?

Tags: vector-spaces, definition

RGB colours are a tuple of three hexadecimal numbers, $(r, g, b)$, where each entry satisfies $0\leq x \leq 15$. So addition is defined such that

> $$
> (r_1, g_1, b_1) + (r_2, g_2, b_2) = (\min(r_1+r_2, 15), \min(g_1+g_2, 15), \min(b_1+b_2, 15))
> $$

because there is a limit to how red, green or blue something can be. Substraction is

> $$
> (r_1, g_1, b_1) - (r_2, g_2, b_2) = (\max(r_1-r_2, 0), \max(g_1-g_2, 0), \max(b_1-b_2, 0))
> $$

This satisfies many of the axioms for a vector space (commutativity, associativity, identity element, etc.), with the exception of unique additive inverses. So it can't be a vector space, but it clearly shares many features. So what is this called? And how can its relationship to a vector space be described?

Comment: "it clearly shares many features": not linearity.

Comment: Your "subtraction" is wrongly defined, it can overflow and the argument $0$ is of no use.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at just the operation of addition, the set forms a *commutative monoid*, but this descriptions only covers the part where a regular vector space is also an Abelian group.

The closest I can find to describing the RGB structure is a [monoid ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid_ring)...